# Node JS as HTTP Server and as tcp socket client at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm creating node js application as a http server that communicate to tcp socket server, and the code look's like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var url = require('url') ;
const PORT=8080;
var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(9000,'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', function(){
    console.log('Connected');
});
function handleRequest(request, response){
    var qo = url.parse(request.url,true).query;
        if(typeof qo.q=="undefined"){
            response.end("ERROR");
        }else{
            client.write(decodeURIComponent(qo.q));
            client.on('data',function(data){
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,X-Powered-ByX-Powered-By','Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*','X-Powered-By':'Poltak ganteng'});
            response.end(data);
            });
        }
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function(){
        console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

i'm afraid that code not working properly to handle multiple request at a time. is there any way to handle multiple request and get correct response to requestor?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use req/res with your socket connection, you want to send uid at each client.write end your other service responde with the same uid for conserve the relation one to one to req/res, you don't have other choice for guaranteed unicities.

Answer (score 0):

The have an expensive resource as TCP client (or clients) that has to be shared among node requests, so [socket-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-pool) can help you on that.